# Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

What is causing this build error:

```
- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.0.3')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    Google
```

in `build.gradle` file

Expecting a successful android build

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795079/error1-0-plugin-with-id-com-android-application-not-found)

Comment: You haven't provided any information, apart from the error. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

From searching it seems like there are a lot of related posts - what have you tried?

Do any of these help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/71780967/

https://stackoverflow.com/q/70947176/

https://stackoverflow.com/q/71427323/

https://stackoverflow.com/q/24795079/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 11):

In my case `settings.gradle` file was missing. You can create a file and place into project root folder.

**settings.gradle**:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "android-geocode"
include ':app'
```

Comment: Happened with me when I migrated my legacy project to ```kotlin-dsl```. ```settings.gradle``` should be extended with ```pluginManagement``` and ```dependencyResolutionManagement``` blocks.

Comment: that was the solution, it should be marked as answer

Comment: this works for me

Answer (score 0):

Check the gradle-wrapper properties version of distributionurl and it should be same as build.gradle's plugin version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As I found, it's happened when the **Gradle** is updated, but it does not match with plugins. So for this issue, first check these steps:

1. Project Setting: `Project -> Gradle Version -> 8.0`
2. Gradle Wrapper: `distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip`
3. **Inactive all plugins**: and Sync Gradle to sure the last Gradle version is downloaded correctly.

If until this step is not solved, please see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77741192/12272687).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add `gradlePluginPortal()` to your repositories?
This worked for me