# Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources

Tags: android

I have some issue with my android studio. I was using my android studio without any issue, but when i have to update my windows and after finished update windows, this issue pop up. i have this issue before, but i fixed it with no proxy, but this time i tried no proxy, it won't solve the problem, does any expert know how to solve it?

[image]
This is what i got in android studio

I have tried several solution:
Reset Java_home,
Reset No proxy,
Reinstall java and android studio

[image]

Comment: Could you please post your build.gradle file?

Comment: @ZsoltBoldizsar I have posted build.gradle

Comment: did you manage to resolve this issue? :)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by changing build.gradle to this:

```
    buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.7.20'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who can't find an answer from the above, in my case I had gradle "offline" mode selected in my gradle file, the solution was to toggle it off

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2do1.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced this issue while using `gradle version 8.2.2` in `Andriod Studio Hedgehog 2023`. Below solution is worked for me. I had changed the gradle JDK version to 17 and sync project again and its working.

`File -> Setting -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle ->Gradle JDK`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that you're missing the `buildscript` block.

You have two options:

1. Declare it at the beginning of your `build.gradle` file as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
}
```

2. Declare it at the beginning of your `settings.gradle` file if you want it to be applied to all your modules in your project (this is generally the case). Read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#settings-gradle):

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```