# Android Studio Error: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.4.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I keep getting this error in Android Studio Electric Eel[image]

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}
```

I've tried using the answers these two posts but nothing works maybe because those posts are older and they were using older versions of Android Studio
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73099487/plugin-id-com-android-application-version-7-2-0-apply-false-was-not-f](https://stackoverflow.com)
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71427323/gradle-sync-failed-plugin-id-com-android-application-version-7-1-2-app](https://stackoverflow.com)

I also reinstalled Android Studio and it still didn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70947176/bumblebee-android-studio-plugin-id-com-android-application-version-7-1-0

Answer (score 3):

I have been stuck for 2 days in this issue now and what solved it for me is in the gradle.properties file(Global Properties), I deleted all proxies and that forced android studios to set the correct ones. I think they got changed because I made an update or something.

Basically delete those

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=
systemProp.http.proxyPort=80
systemProp.https.proxyHost=
systemProp.https.proxyPort=80
```

And let android studio do them for you.

Comment: Additionally in my case, enabled VPN caused this error

Answer (score 2):

**Setting>Build, appearance, deployment>Gradle**
[image]Gradle JDK: Jbr-11

I was having the same problem but by using this progress I have solved that problem. You should also try this I hope this will work.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code to the settings.gradle.kts file

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so... here's what could be causing this problem of yours and how you might be able to solve it :

The main reason why this happens is that obviously as it shows it can't find certain versions of stuff in your gradle files and a possible fix could be to change the location of "**gradle user home**" to your project's gradle folder which is "**\path_to_your_project\.gradle**" as shown in this picture :

( You can find the mentioned setting in **Settings-> Build, Execution, Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle** )

[click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHDFn.png)

I had a similar problem recently and this way I was able to fix it so I hope it works for you too !

Answer (score 0):

*Today I solved it. Previously I set up Gradle JDK: Jbr-11*.
My country has internet restrictions so I use "Proton VPN" (free version), and NetLimiter 4 Pro as a firewall to conect my laptop.

**The problem dissapeared when i turned off my firewall**, with the VPN on. Android Studio started to download files it needed. It worked due the firewall was blocking an Android Studio task i hadn't seen.

But then another problem appeared in activity_main.xml: "*Class referenced in the layout file, 'androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout', was not found in the project or the libraries* "

To solve this, try:

1. Open your build.gradle (application-level) file and make sure that it has the ConstraintLayout dependency.

   dependencies {
   implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
   //...
   }

   If the dependency is not there, add the dependency in the build.gradle file and synchronize the project.
2. If dependency was already there, try cleaning up and rebuilding your project. Build -> Clean Project,
   when it finished:
   Build -> Rebuild Project.
3. Delete the .idea folder and let these files download when you open Android Studio. (This is what finally worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, it was with conflict of JDK version. So the problem is [Compatibility](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html).
Use right Java version and Gradle version to support it.
Now i use Gradle JDK corretto-19.

Answer (score 0):

As Other friends mentioned, may be is about VPN or Proxy, but not all.

For this issue, first check these steps:

- Project Setting:

  Project -> Gradle Version -> 8.0
- Gradle Wrapper:

  distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip
- Inactive all plugins, and **Sync Gradle** to sure the last Gradle version
  is downloaded correctly.

  // id 'com.android.application' version '7.5.0' apply false

If there is any **error like 403 or forbidden** try new proxy, otherwise please see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77741192/12272687).