# Android Gradle Plugin 8.0.2, Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.0.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources

Tags: android-studio

I have installed the latest version of Android Studio and created a new project, but I am unable to run it due to the plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.0.2', apply: false] not being found in any of the following sources: [image]

I have tried almost all the solution which have mentioned in stackOverFlow. Can anyone please help here how to solve this problem ?

Comment: I am having the same problem with an old Android app.
I tried adding:
`
org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home
`
to my gradle-wrapper.properties file but it did not help.

Comment: upload gradle wrapper properties file in question.

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue after importing a module, my project is using Gradle.kts
The issue was that the import added a `settings.gradle` file where it added the `inclide ':newModule'` line but as my project is using Kotlin gradle I just needed to move that `inclide ':newModule'` into my existing `settings.gradle.kts` file as `include(":newModule")` and delete the `settings.gradle`

Comment: It did not occur to me that the mere existence of that file `settings.gradle` would cause this issue. I swear everytime I setup a new Android project I have to spend half a day just getting it to build an empty project. Thanks !.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by decreasing plugin version from 8.3.0 to 8.1.0 after updating Gradle JDK Version to the latest 21.0.1. I don't know which part works but these are all I do.

I hope this helps.

Comment: In my case I just had to downgrade the plugin version from 8.2.0 to 8.1.0

Comment: in which gradle jdk version need to change?

Answer (score 2):

There may be several reasons for the sync to fails:

- the Gradle Plugin version may be incompatible with the Gradle Version, you can check the compatibility there: https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle. If it is incompatible you need to upgrade gradle by upgrading the `distributionUrl` of `gradle-wrapper.properties`
- If you have migrated the plugins declaration in the root build.gradle file from `dependencies { classpath() {} }` to `plugins { id "" version "" }` you also need to upgrade `settings.gradle` and add a `pluginManagement.repositories` block as mentioned here: https://developer.android.com/build#settings-file

Comment: Thank you very much Jonathan! Your second point saved me.

Comment: your first solution did the trick for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue as you. I think the problem is Android Studio version, and you can try updating it to the latest version. However, if you don't want to use the new features with Gradle 8, you can simply use Gradle version 7 instead.
eg.
gradle== 7.2
gradle plugin== 7.1.2

is work for me, hope this helps

This is my reference link：

https://sebhastian.com/plugin-with-id-com-android-application-not-found/

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?hl=zh-cn#updating-gradle

Answer (score 1):

run into same error "Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.2.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources"

info:
Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-231.9392.1.2311.11330709, built on January 19, 2024

```kotlin
build.gradle.kts

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
}
```

try to change gradle plugin and gradle version, does not work for me...
Then try to change Gradle JDK version. Wow, It works! Thought it might be JDK version have to be updated too with new version gradle daemon.

for reference only, use JDK version 20.0.1 with gradle 8.2.2

Comment: I am getting same error, please let me know where we can set JDK version in new Android Studio Hedgehog ?

Comment: Settings -> Build Tools -> Gradle, "Gradle JDK" is to be found inside "Gradle Projects"

Answer (score 0):

Edit file setting.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "com.yourpackagename"
include ':app'`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing the same problem for two days and tried the solutions above but unfortunatelly didn't work.

So my problem was with the distributionUrl value and the kotlin version (needed upgrade):

1. in my `gradle-wrapper.properties` I changed the distributionUrl value:

   ...

   distributionUrl = https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip

   ...
2. Updated Kotlin version to 1.7.20

Note: My `com.android.application` version on `build.gradle` is:     `id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.0' apply false`

Answer (score 0):

**build.gradle(project: demoApp)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.0' apply false
}
```

**build.gradle(Module: app)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.coding.demo'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.coding.demo"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
#Sun Oct 08 18:08:05 IST 2023
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

**settings.gradle**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "demoapp"
include ':app'
```

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, first check these steps:

1. Project Setting:

   Project -> Gradle Version -> 8.0
2. Gradle Wrapper:

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip

3. then inactive all plugins, and Sync Gradle to sure the last Gradle version is downloaded correctly.

   // id 'com.android.application' version '7.5.0' apply false
4. If there isn't any download, then Active one by one to download all.
5. Change to new version: [check here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.library/com.android.library.gradle.plugin)

   id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.1' apply false

   id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.0' apply false
6. For `com.android.library' version '8.2.0'` need to upgrade Gradle minimum 8.2

Answer (score 0):

i realized i had put this line in settings.gradle

id "com.android.application" version "8.2" apply false

but cahnging to this solved the issue

id "com.android.application" version "8.2.0" apply false

The diffrence was just the zero at the end

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, the problem is `Gradle sync` and `Gradle update` after a software update or something like that. In some regions, google services aren't available  properly or completely filtered from google side or even government of that special region.
a proper connection with the help of a proper VPN or Proxy and a successful update and sync of Gradle with project will fix the problem automatically.