# "id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.3.0', apply: false" when importing module (openCV)

Tags: android, opencv

I'm new to Android. I want to connect ESP32 cam with android and process using openCV.

I downloaded the latest version of Android studio and want to import some module (openCV). Both the Android studio and the openCV is the latest version

After I import the module and the gradle sync i got this kind of
[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlFnU.png)

I already tried to lower the gradle version but the issue persist. I already tried what was written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76620079/android-gradle-plugin-8-0-2-plugin-id-com-android-application-version-8) but no luck.